# Calculating win probability in a specific game of chance

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a "game" (scare quotes because there's no strategy involved, just pure luck) with the following rules:

Each of two players begins with some number of pieces (not necessarily the same number for both players), each labeled with a digit between 1 and 6. On each player's turn, they roll two dice. For each die, if a player holds a piece labeled with that die's number, that piece is eliminated. The winner is the first player to eliminate all their pieces.

My question is how to determine which player is more likely to win given the number and distribution of their pieces. Two points are obvious:

- Having fewer pieces than your opponent makes you more likely to win;
- Having pieces that are more evenly distributed than your opponent makes you more likely to win.

To illustrate the second point, if one player has [1,2,3,4,5,6] and the other has [1,1,1,1,1,1], the first will benefit from any die roll while the second will only benefit from a 1.

How do these two factors interact? I did some coding and found that in practice, [1,2,3,4,5,6] seems to beat [1,1,1] more often than not, but lose to [1,1] or [1,1,2]; [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4] and [6,6,6,6,6] are about evenly matched; etc. But is there some general formula which, given how many pieces each player has and how many distinct digits they represent, can tell you who has the higher win probability?

Comment: since the dice roles are independent, the only thing that should affect the chances of winning is the number of pieces

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about general formula, but a recursion can be formed like this:

**Notation:**

- Call the players A and B. A goes first.
- Let a die have $d$ faces (so we generalize a bit from the case $d=6$). Let $[d] = \{1,2,\dots, d\}$ be the set of possible values (when coding, this is zero-based, but that doesn't matter).
- The number of dice thrown each turn is $k$ (in original question $k=2$).
- Hand is a multiset of pieces. For coding purposes encode it as a $d$-tuple telling the number of each piece. E.g the hand $\{1,1,3,5,5,6,6,6\}$ encodes as $(2,0,1,0,2,3)$.
- The size of a hand $H$ is $|H|$ equals to number of its elements which can also be gotten as sum of its encoding.
- $p(A,B) = \mathbb{P}(\text{A wins} |\text{player A has hand } A, \text{player B has hand } B)$

**The recursion:**

We have, by conditioning on the outcome of two turns (i.e both A and B throw once)

$$p(A,B) = \sum_{d_A, d_B \in [d]^{k}} \frac{1}{d^{2k}}p(A-d_A, B-d_B).$$

Here in the indexing a tuple is considered as a multiset: $(d_1, d_2) = \{d_1, d_2\}$. Minus means multiset difference. For some values of $(d_A, d_B) \in [d]^{2k}$, it happens that both $A - d_A = A$ and $B-d_B=B$. Call the set of these $D_{\text{self loop}}$. Denote

$$p_\text{self loop}(A,B) = \sum_{(d_A,d_B)\in D_{\text{self loop}}} \frac{1}{d^{2k}}.$$

Move these terms to other side, take $p(A,B)$ as common factor and divide by $1-p_\text{self loop}(A,B)$ to obtain the recursion

$$p(A, B) = \frac{1}{d^{2k}(1-p_\text{self loop}(A,B))} \sum_{(d_A, d_B) \notin D_{\text{self loop}}} p(A-d_A, B-d_B).$$

The base case is

$$p(A,B) = \begin{cases}1, \text{ if } |A|=0 \\
0, \text{ if } |B|=0 \text{ and } |A|>0
\end{cases}$$

The condition $|A|>0$ in the last case follows from the fact that player A goes first. This of course gives them an upper hand so maybe we could consider it a tie if both players eliminate their cards in the last round(?) This would perhaps make the comparison of hands more meaningful since it doesn't matter which one starts.

**Code:**

Here is a Python code. I have reduced the set $[d]^k$ by ignoring the order of elements of a tuple ($(d_1, d_2)$ and $(d_2, d_1)$ are the same throw of dice). I also made the function `expectedRounds(A)` that calculates the expected number of throws before a player eliminates all his pieces in a single player game. I haven't yet even tested this hypothesis, but might it be that who has a lower expectation of rounds, also has a higher probability to win? At least if ties are allowed (i.e. B has a tasoittava siirto)?

```
from fractions import Fraction
from itertools import product

def killPieces(H, dH):
    ret = list(H)
    kills = 0
    for j in dH:
        if ret[j]>0:
            ret[j] -= 1
            kills += 1
    return tuple(ret), kills

def getOutcomeProbs(d, k):
    ret = {}
    for ds in product(*[range(d) for _ in range(k)]):
        dKey = tuple(sorted(ds))
        if dKey not in ret: ret[dKey] = Fraction(0,1)
        ret[dKey] += Fraction(1, d**k)
    return ret

def winProbA(A0,B0,k=2):
    d = len(A0)
    memo = {}
    dOutcomes = getOutcomeProbs(d, k)
        
    def rec(A, B, aSize, bSize):
        if aSize == 0: return 1 #and bSize>0 if consider ties
        if bSize ==0: return 0
        memoKey = (A,B)
        if memoKey in memo: return memo[memoKey]
        selfLoopProb = 0
        tot = 0
        for dA in dOutcomes:
            for dB in dOutcomes:
                dProb = dOutcomes[dA]*dOutcomes[dB]
                (A2,kA), (B2,kB) = tuple(killPieces(H, dH)
                            for H, dH in zip((A,B), (dA,dB)))
                if kA==0 and kB==0:
                    selfLoopProb += dProb
                else:
                    tot += rec(A2, B2, aSize-kA, bSize-kB)*dProb
        ret = Fraction(tot, 1-selfLoopProb)
        memo[memoKey] = ret
        return ret

    return rec(A0, B0, sum(A0), sum(B0))

def expectedRounds(A0, k=2):
    d = len(A0)
    memo = {}
    dOutcomes = getOutcomeProbs(d, k)
    def rec(A, aSize):
        if aSize==0: return 0
        memoKey = A
        if memoKey in memo: return memo[memoKey]
        selfLoopProb = 0
        tot = 0
        for dA in dOutcomes:
            A2,kA = killPieces(A, dA)
            if kA==0:
                selfLoopProb += dOutcomes[dA]
            else:
                tot += dOutcomes[dA]*rec(A2, aSize-kA)
        ret = Fraction(1+tot, 1-selfLoopProb)
        memo[memoKey] = ret
        return ret
    return rec(A0, sum(A0))


testA = (1,1,1,1,1,1)
testB = (3,0,0,0,0,0)
sol = winProbA(testA, testB)
print ("P(A win) = %s = %f" %(sol, float(sol)))
for name, hand in (("A", testA), ("B", testB)):
    val = expectedRounds(hand)
    print ("E[rounds %s] = %s = %f" %(name, val, float(val)))
```

**Outcomes:**

"[1,2,3,4,5,6] seems to beat [1,1,1]". This is true according to my code

- `winProbA((1,1,1,1,1,1), (3, 0,0,0,0,0))` $= \frac{4243418363252787182233809530375}{6635594916756251318014016947072} = 0.6394932807813927$

The other examples you gave also hold

- `winProbA((1,1,1,1,1,1), (2,0,0,0,0,0)) = 0.3943528105605558`
- `winProbA((1,1,1,1,1,1), (2,1,0,0,0,0)) = 0.46939054384024037`

The evenly matched case [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4] and [6,6,6,6,6] (`A=(1,2,3,4,0,0), B=(0,0,0,0,0,5)`) is a win for A with probability $0.5525691535607143$. If ties are allowed, we get that win probability for A is $0.49652535557197713$ and for B $0.44743084643928566$, so A is still more likely to win than B.

Comment: I just realized we could reduce the number of states, since in a hand it doesn't matter what die-values you have, just how many of each. So we could sort the encoding of a hand.

Comment: Yes, I think just add `A2, B2 = (tuple(sorted(H)) for H in (A2,B2))` right before `tot += ...`